# SpriteKit Collision lag

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I've got a scene where a certain number of nodes spawn at the top of the screen and another batch of nodes at the bottom. Now if they collide, I want the game to end which it does, the only problem is that the collision causes a major frame drop or stutter/lag whatever you can think. It basically stops the game for a second and it continues.

The nodes don't have textures. There are no sounds playing when the nodes collide. I've stripped everything down and left just the nodes to collide and the problem persists. I can't point a finger at where it's really coming from since i've left nothing unturned and the scene is not complex 8/9 nodes most at a time.

This doesn't always happen sometimes the nodes collide and everything runs smooth. The only other information i can provide is that the nodes are moving rather fast so they fly in and out of the scene within 0.05 seconds which i tried setting it to a longer duration the problem still persists just more rarely. When the game is over the user has the option to present the scene again which adds the scene from the beginning.

This question leans more toward people who might have had a similar issue , since I don't know what more information I can provide. (Square nodes collide right away the game stops for a second and continues). Thanks.

Comment: Do you use SKSpriteNodes ? What are nodes and draws count (you can enable these in view controller) ? Can you update your question with a code which can produce described behaviour ? Does this happen on simulator or device  ?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the lack of a more precise description but this seems weird to me  and i can't exactly pin point where the issue is coming from. I am using a SKSpriteNode for the obstacles and the player nodes. The node count doesn't go above 11 the draw count is 6-7? and the game runs at 60 fps until contact happens where it dips to well. below 20. The issue occurs both in the simulator and device. I am currently not using any textures. Whats confusing me is that the issue is not always consistent . Thanks for your interest

Comment: I suggest you post the code in `didBeginContact`.

Comment: Figured it out , while looking at the code in didBeginContact, where i call my gameOver function, when the game is over i present a SKLabelNode, which while trying to figure out the issue i removed everything but one thing that  is i had misspelled the fonts name.. ! Everything showed up fine but i had one wrong letter in my font name. Thanks 0x141E and Whirlwind.